# R sjplot: How to angle the X axis labels and move them down?

Tags: r, graphing, sjplot

In sjplot you can angle the x axis labels by adding axis.angle = # in the theme. However, this makes the label overlap the x-axis. How do you shift them down so everything is more easy to read? In ggplot, you can use hjust in the axis.text.x theme line, but this does not seem to work for sjplot.

I would add an image, but I do not have enough points on Stack overflow yet to do so. See the code below for an example.

Sample Code:

```
# load libraries
library(sjPlot)  # for plotting
library(sjmisc)  # for sample data
library(ggplot2) # to access ggplot-themes

# load sample data set
data(efc)

set_theme(
  geom.outline.color = "antiquewhite4", 
  geom.outline.size = 1, 
  geom.label.size = 2,
  geom.label.color = "grey50",
  title.color = "red", 
  title.size = 1.5, 
  axis.angle.x = 45, 
  axis.textcolor = "blue", 
  base = theme_bw()
)

plot_grpfrq(
  efc$e42dep, 
  efc$e16sex, 
  title = NULL, 
  geom.colors = c("cadetblue", "coral"), 
  geom.size = 0.4
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I modified the `sjPlot::set_theme` function adding the `axis.hjust.x` option.

```
my_set_theme <- function (base = theme_grey(), theme.font = NULL, title.color = "black", 
    title.size = 1.2, title.align = "left", title.vjust = NULL, 
    geom.outline.color = NULL, geom.outline.size = 0, geom.boxoutline.size = 0.5, 
    geom.boxoutline.color = "black", geom.alpha = 1, geom.linetype = 1, 
    geom.errorbar.size = 0.7, geom.errorbar.linetype = 1, geom.label.color = NULL, 
    geom.label.size = 4, geom.label.alpha = 1, geom.label.angle = 0, 
    axis.title.color = "grey30", axis.title.size = 1.1, axis.title.x.vjust = NULL, 
    axis.title.y.vjust = NULL, axis.angle.x = 0, axis.angle.y = 0, 
    axis.angle = NULL, axis.textcolor.x = "grey30", axis.textcolor.y = "grey30", 
    axis.textcolor = NULL, axis.linecolor.x = NULL, axis.linecolor.y = NULL, 
    axis.linecolor = NULL, axis.line.size = 0.5, axis.textsize.x = 1, axis.hjust.x=NULL,
    axis.textsize.y = 1, axis.textsize = NULL, axis.tickslen = NULL, 
    axis.tickscol = NULL, axis.ticksmar = NULL, axis.ticksize.x = NULL, 
    axis.ticksize.y = NULL, panel.backcol = NULL, panel.bordercol = NULL, 
    panel.col = NULL, panel.major.gridcol = NULL, panel.minor.gridcol = NULL, 
    panel.gridcol = NULL, panel.gridcol.x = NULL, panel.gridcol.y = NULL, 
    panel.major.linetype = 1, panel.minor.linetype = 1, plot.backcol = NULL, 
    plot.bordercol = NULL, plot.col = NULL, plot.margins = NULL, 
    legend.pos = "right", legend.just = NULL, legend.inside = FALSE, 
    legend.size = 1, legend.color = "black", legend.title.size = 1, 
    legend.title.color = "black", legend.title.face = "bold", 
    legend.backgroundcol = "white", legend.bordercol = "white", 
    legend.item.size = NULL, legend.item.backcol = "grey90", 
    legend.item.bordercol = "white") 
{
    sjtheme <- NULL
    if (is.null(geom.label.color)) {
        geom.label.color <- "black"
    }
    if (!is.null(axis.angle)) {
        axis.angle.x <- axis.angle.y <- axis.angle
    }
    else {
        axis.angle <- axis.angle.x
    }
    if (!is.null(axis.textcolor)) {
        axis.textcolor.x <- axis.textcolor.y <- axis.textcolor
    }
    else {
        if (is.null(axis.textcolor.x)) 
            axis.textcolor <- axis.textcolor.y
        else axis.textcolor <- axis.textcolor.x
    }
    if (!is.null(axis.linecolor)) {
        axis.linecolor.x <- axis.linecolor.y <- axis.linecolor
    }
    else {
        if (is.null(axis.linecolor.x)) 
            axis.linecolor <- axis.linecolor.y
        else axis.linecolor <- axis.linecolor.x
    }
    if (!is.null(axis.textsize)) {
        axis.textsize.x <- axis.textsize.y <- axis.textsize
    }
    else {
        if (is.null(axis.textsize.x)) 
            axis.textsize <- axis.textsize.y
        else axis.textsize <- axis.textsize.x
    }
    if (!is.null(panel.gridcol)) {
        panel.major.gridcol <- panel.minor.gridcol <- panel.gridcol
    }
    else {
        if (is.null(panel.major.gridcol)) 
            panel.gridcol <- panel.minor.gridcol
        else panel.gridcol <- panel.major.gridcol
    }
    if (!is.null(panel.col)) {
        panel.backcol <- panel.bordercol <- panel.col
    }
    else {
        if (is.null(panel.backcol)) 
            panel.col <- panel.bordercol
        else panel.col <- panel.backcol
    }
    if (!is.null(title.align)) {
        if (title.align == "left" || title.align == "l") 
            title.align <- 0
        if (title.align == "right" || title.align == "r") 
            title.align <- 1
        if (title.align == "center" || title.align == "c") 
            title.align <- 0.5
    }
    else {
        title.align <- 0
    }
    if (!is.null(plot.col)) {
        plot.backcol <- plot.bordercol <- plot.col
    }
    else {
        if (is.null(plot.backcol)) 
            plot.col <- plot.bordercol
        else plot.col <- plot.backcol
    }
    if (legend.inside) {
        if (is.character(legend.pos)) {
            if (legend.pos == "top right") 
                legend.pos <- c(1, 1)
            else if (legend.pos == "bottom right") 
                legend.pos <- c(1, 0)
            else if (legend.pos == "bottom left") 
                legend.pos <- c(0, 0)
            else if (legend.pos == "top left") 
                legend.pos <- c(0, 1)
            if (is.null(legend.just)) 
                legend.just <- legend.pos
        }
    }
    if (is.null(legend.just)) 
        legend.just <- "center"
    if (!is.null(theme) && any(class(theme) == "theme") && any(class(theme) == 
        "gg")) {
        theme_set(theme)
    }
    else if (!is.null(base) && any(class(base) == "theme") && 
        any(class(base) == "gg")) {
        sjtheme <- base + theme(plot.title = element_text(size = rel(title.size), 
            colour = title.color, hjust = title.align), axis.text = element_text(angle = axis.angle, 
            size = rel(axis.textsize), colour = axis.textcolor), 
            axis.text.x = element_text(angle = axis.angle.x, 
                size = rel(axis.textsize.x), colour = axis.textcolor.x, hjust=axis.hjust.x), 
            axis.text.y = element_text(angle = axis.angle.y, 
                size = rel(axis.textsize.y), colour = axis.textcolor.y), 
            axis.title = element_text(size = rel(axis.title.size), 
                colour = axis.title.color), legend.position = legend.pos, 
            legend.justification = legend.just, legend.text = element_text(size = rel(legend.size), 
                colour = legend.color), legend.title = element_text(size = rel(legend.title.size), 
                colour = legend.title.color, face = legend.title.face), 
            legend.background = element_rect(colour = legend.bordercol, 
                fill = legend.backgroundcol))
        if (!is.null(theme.font)) {
            sjtheme <- sjtheme + theme(text = element_text(family = theme.font))
        }
        if (!is.null(legend.item.backcol)) {
            sjtheme <- sjtheme + theme(legend.key = element_rect(colour = legend.item.bordercol, 
                fill = legend.item.backcol))
        }
        if (!is.null(legend.item.size)) {
            sjtheme <- sjtheme + theme(legend.key.size = unit(legend.item.size, 
                "cm"))
        }
        if (!is.null(axis.linecolor)) {
            sjtheme <- sjtheme + theme(axis.line = element_line(colour = axis.linecolor, 
                size = axis.line.size), axis.line.x = element_line(colour = axis.linecolor.x), 
                axis.line.y = element_line(colour = axis.linecolor.y))
        }
        if (!is.null(axis.tickscol)) {
            sjtheme <- sjtheme + theme(axis.ticks = element_line(colour = axis.tickscol))
        }
        if (!is.null(axis.tickslen)) {
            sjtheme <- sjtheme + theme(axis.ticks.length = unit(axis.tickslen, 
                "cm"))
        }
        if (!is.null(axis.ticksmar)) {
            sjtheme <- sjtheme + theme(axis.text = element_text(margin = margin(t = axis.ticksmar, 
                unit = "cm")))
        }
        if (!is.null(axis.ticksize.x)) {
            sjtheme <- sjtheme + theme(axis.ticks.x = element_line(size = axis.ticksize.x))
        }
        if (!is.null(axis.ticksize.y)) {
            sjtheme <- sjtheme + theme(axis.ticks.y = element_line(size = axis.ticksize.y))
        }
        if (!is.null(plot.col)) {
            sjtheme <- sjtheme + theme(plot.background = element_rect(colour = plot.bordercol, 
                fill = plot.backcol))
        }
        if (!is.null(panel.col)) {
            sjtheme <- sjtheme + theme(panel.background = element_rect(colour = panel.bordercol, 
                fill = panel.backcol), panel.border = element_rect(colour = panel.bordercol))
        }
        if (!is.null(panel.gridcol)) {
            sjtheme <- sjtheme + theme(panel.grid.minor = element_line(colour = panel.minor.gridcol, 
                linetype = panel.minor.linetype), panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = panel.major.gridcol, 
                linetype = panel.major.linetype))
        }
        if (!is.null(plot.margins)) {
            sjtheme <- sjtheme + theme(plot.margin = plot.margins)
        }
        if (!is.null(plot.margins)) {
            sjtheme <- sjtheme + theme(plot.margin = plot.margins)
        }
        if (!is.null(title.vjust)) {
            sjtheme <- sjtheme + theme(plot.title = element_text(vjust = title.vjust))
        }
        if (!is.null(axis.title.x.vjust)) {
            sjtheme <- sjtheme + theme(axis.title.x = element_text(vjust = axis.title.x.vjust))
        }
        if (!is.null(axis.title.y.vjust)) {
            sjtheme <- sjtheme + theme(axis.title.y = element_text(vjust = axis.title.y.vjust))
        }
        if (!is.null(panel.gridcol.x)) {
            sjtheme <- sjtheme + theme(panel.grid.minor.x = element_line(colour = panel.gridcol.x, 
                linetype = panel.minor.linetype), panel.grid.major.x = element_line(colour = panel.gridcol.x, 
                linetype = panel.major.linetype))
        }
        if (!is.null(panel.gridcol.y)) {
            sjtheme <- sjtheme + theme(panel.grid.minor.y = element_line(colour = panel.gridcol.y, 
                linetype = panel.minor.linetype), panel.grid.major.y = element_line(colour = panel.gridcol.y, 
                linetype = panel.major.linetype))
        }
        theme_set(sjtheme)
    }
    else {
        warning("Either `theme` or `base` must be supplied as ggplot-theme-object to set global theme options for sjPlot.", 
            call. = F)
    }
    sjPlot:::sj.theme_geoms(geom.alpha, geom.linetype, geom.outline.size, 
        geom.outline.color, geom.boxoutline.size, geom.boxoutline.color, 
        geom.errorbar.size, geom.errorbar.linetype, geom.label.size, 
        geom.label.color, geom.label.alpha, geom.label.angle)
    invisible(sjtheme)
}
```

The code for generating your plot is

```
my_set_theme(
  geom.outline.color = "antiquewhite4", 
  geom.outline.size = 1, 
  geom.label.size = 2,
  geom.label.color = "grey50",
  title.color = "red", 
  title.size = 1.5, 
  axis.angle.x = 45, 
  axis.textcolor = "blue", 
  axis.hjust.x = 1,         # <- This is the new option !
  base = theme_bw()
)

plot_grpfrq(
  efc$e42dep, 
  efc$e16sex, 
  title = NULL, 
  geom.colors = c("cadetblue", "coral"), 
  geom.size = 0.4
)
```

[image]